# Reduce in scala (not Spark)

Tags: scala, mapreduce, sbt

I've got this data:

```
(15,ArrayBuffer((1038,1)))
(14,ArrayBuffer((1031,1), (1003,1)))
(110,ArrayBuffer((1035,1))
```

so Group and Map have already been executed.
Now I have to do a Reduce Step,
the result that I want is:

```
(15,1)
(14,2)
(110,1)
```

a simply count map-reduce.
But I can not write a reduce Step ( I have to do write a sum of any 1 term -dummy- in array buffer)

Comment: How is this different from a simple map ? `data.map { case (x, y) => (x, y.length) }`

Comment: no works, y.lenght is not recognized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can use a map and the size of the ArrayBuffer

```
import scala.collection.mutable._ 

Seq((15,ArrayBuffer((1038,1)))
     ,(14,ArrayBuffer((1031,1),(1003,1)))
     ,(110,ArrayBuffer((1035,1))))
  .map { case (x,y) => (x,y.size) }
```

**res2: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[(Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((15,1), (14,2), (110,1))**